# getting Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 even when im returning json from flask backend

Tags: python, json, reactjs, flask, fetch

I'm learning how to use flask as backend for react app from [this article](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-create-a-react--flask-project), my flask backend has only one route, which returns current time in JSON. to my react app when fetched, but my dev console says -
`Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

I did some research on this, turns out this happens when you are not returning json. But as far as i know flask automatically `jsonifyies` dicts. So please explain where im going wrong.

Here is my react code (only the relevant parts, i did not include jsx as it would make this unnecessarily long) -

```
    async function get_data() {
        try {
            const res = await fetch("/hola");
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("error : " + err);
        }
    }
    function onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const stuff = get_data();
        console.log(stuff);
    }
```

So i basically press a submit button on the webpage, and that should get the data from my flask backed and log it in console.

Here is my flask code -

```
from flask import Flask
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/hola')
def home():
    return {'time': time.time()}
```

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` because your route is almost certainly returning an HTML error code 500 and a corresponding html message, hence the message starting with a `<`, as in something like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

See attached screenshot of the error in Chrome browser:

[image: return code 500 with html error message]

Try rewriting your `hola` route as the following and see what exception is being raised:

```
@app.route('/hola')
def home():
    try:
        return {'time': time.time()}
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
        return {'time': None}
```

I suspect you have another variable called time somewhere in your script which doesn't have a function `time()`. For example, here's one way of causing the error:

```
@app.route('/hola')
def time():
    try:
        return {'time': time.time()}
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
        return {'time': None}
```

Note I have stupidly called my route function `time`. Here is the exception output:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 201.7846.77)
 * Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2020 12:50:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 'function' object has no attribute 'time'
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2020 12:50:00] "GET /hola HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

And here is the response in the browser:

[image: Exception caught and return JSON]

Answer (score 0):

you need to jsonifiy the dictionary before returning

try

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/hola')
def home():
    return jsonify({'time': time.time()})
```

Comment: hey thanks, but that doesnt seem to work . I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason for this issue, I too faced that but in jquery. The reason is the data type from the backend is a script but in response, it's expecting the JSON data. You have to use JSON.stringify(data), when you are getting or updating the data.